# Find all ids which lie between Range and are present in a common foreign key id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want all the specific Ids which have a common other Id. I am sending the data through an user-defined table type.

```
CREATE TYPE rangeType AS TABLE (
     ID2 int NOT NULL,
     StartRange int NULL,
     EndRange int NULL
);
```

The table is Like the following

```
ID1    ID2    Value
 11      2       3
 12      2       4
 12      3       8.9
 15      3       10
 15      2       4
```

The value I will send will be of the form

```
DECLARE @temp_table rangeType
Insert INTO @temp_table values (2,4,10)
INSERT INTO @temp_table values (3,5,10)
```

So I want Output to be all those ID1's which have both the value of ID2 as 2 and 3 and the rows which have ID2 as 2 should have a value between 4 and 10 and all those rows which have ID2 as 3 should have a value between 5 and 10.

So my output, in this case, should be

```
ID1
12
15
```

as the ID1 `12` and `15` maps both `2` and `3` and have the ranges between the specified respective ranges.

I Tried an inner join on the table followed by a `BETWEEN` operator. Which is giving me a correct value the operation which is performed is OR operation rather than an AND operation which I want.

Comment: Hopefully the question is clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
    SELECT ID1 FROM TABLE
WHERE ID2 IN (2,3)
AND 
CASE WHEN ID2 = 2 AND VALUE >= 4 AND VALUE >=10 THEN 1
     WHEN ID2 = 3 AND VALUE >= 5 AND VALUE >=10 THEN 1
     ELSE 0 
END = 1;
```

Comment: Hey @Jim .. The values are not fixed and I am sending a list of Id's and Value as an user-defined data-type